# Error in write.mi(imputations) : could not find function "write.mi"

Tags: r, error-handling, mi

I have installed and loaded the mi package for imputations. I finished the imputations but there are some functions that are supposed to be a part of mi that give me errors saying they cannot find the functions.

I've tried reinstalling/reloading mi, I've updated my R Studio and R package as well.

```
'all.imputations <- mi.completed(imputations)'

'write.mi(imputations)'

'lm.mi(outcome ~ variable1 + variable2,
  data = imputations, m = NULL)'
```

> Error in mi.completed(imputations) : 
>     could not find function "mi.completed"
>
> Error in write.mi(imputations) : could not find function "write.mi"
>
> Error in lm.mi(outcome ~ variable1 + variable2, data = imputations,  : 
>     could not find function "lm.mi"

Comment: I don't see functions named `mi.completed` or `write.mi` defined in the `mi` package.  Why do you think these functions are supposed to exist? Are you following a (possibly outdated) guide or something?

Comment: @MrFlick I was using article "Multiple Imputation with Diagnostics (mi) in R:
Opening Windows into the Black Box"

Comment: Yeah, that's an old guide and those functions don't exist any more. That paper used version `0.09-13`. You can download that version from the archives and see what those functions did. Or you can talk more about exactly what you need to accomplish and see if there's a more modern way to do it.

Comment: @MrFlick ahhh okay, thanks for your help! My specific problem I'm trying to solve is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58630762/error-when-trying-to-use-imputed-data-for-sem-using-mi-package so one idea that I was trying to do to work around the issue was with write.mi so that I could download the imputed data and reupload it with my original data set so I could use a path model with it? Not sure if that makes sense or would work?