# Error when trying to use imputed data for sem using "mi" package

Tags: r, error-handling, imputation, structural-equation-model, mi

I am trying to conduct a path model with my imputed data but I can't figure out how to get my code to work.

A regular regression like this works fine with the pool function

```
analysis <- pool(outcome1 ~ variable1 + variable2,
             data = imputations, m = NULL)
```

But when I try to make it a path model it gives me errors.

e.g., of code I've tried

```
analysis <- pool(outcome1 + outcome2 ~ variable1 + variable2,
             data = imputations, m = NULL)
```

> Error in pool(outcome1 + outcome2 ~ variable1 + variable2, data = imputations,  : 
>     no variable called outcome1 + outcome2 possibly due to typo or transformation, in which case you need to specify 'FUN' explicitly

```
analysis <- sem(pool(outcome1 + outcome2 ~ variable1 + variable2,
             data = imputations, m = NULL))
```

> Error in pool(outcome1 + outcome2 ~ variable1 + variable2, data = imputations,  : 
>     no variable called outcome1 + outcome2 possibly due to typo or transformation, in which case you need to specify 'FUN' explicitly

```
analysis <- pool(outcome1 ~ variable1 + variable2
                  outcome2 ~ variable1 + variable2,
             data = imputations, m = NULL)
```

> Error: unexpected ',' in "                 data = imputations,"

```
analysis <- 'outcome1 ~ variable1 + variable2
              outcome2 ~ variable1 + variable2'

 path <- sem(pool(analysis, data=imputations, m=NULL))
```

> .Error in pool(analysis, data = imputations, m = NULL) : 
>     'formula' must be a formula

I'm still new to r, any ideas of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The manual page for `pool` in the `mi` package says that it takes a `glm` formula. Why do you think it can take a path model formula? It looks like `mice` and `Amelia` support path models.

Comment: @dcarlson okay thanks! I avoided using MICE or Amelia because there is an assumption that the data is missing at random, and my data is likely not missing at random